# Add quotes to a string to make it JSON in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, .net-core, json.net

I'm using a service which uses JSON format.

But from where I am getting JSON does not contain double quotes around key and values.

This is example of the data which I am having

```
[{name:{buyerfirstname:Randy, buyermiddlename:null, buyerlastname:Johnson}, buyerfullname:Randy Johnson, businessname:null}]
```

How can i convert this to JSON in C#

Note: null should not contain double quotes

Comment: It's not JSON if property names and string values are not quoted.

Comment: So `buyerfullname` is just dumped in there, whitespace and all? What kind of service is this...?

Comment: You (or your web service) are confusing a Javascript litteral object with JSON

Comment: You can serialize your C# model to Json through JSON Serializer. 
Fro example: [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: @Pac0 It's not even that

Comment: Not unless you write your own parser to convert as the above value in OP is not a JSON (no quotes around keys and values)

Comment: Yes, I know i need to convert it to JSON by binding quotes around key and value

Comment: @ChrisG yeah, you're right...

Comment: You should fix or cancel the service, depending on which of the two is possible.

Comment: Can you not fix the source that is sending this data?

Comment: No, as this system is very old i managed to get this. Now need to create a parser which adds quotes around it

Comment: I felt something bad in my stomach with this string. I can't figure but maybe we can use a regex.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq Not getting proper regex that I can use

Comment: In that case we're back at "what have you tried, how did it fail?" Right now this question is "gimme the code".

Comment: Agreed with @ChrisG. There are literally thousand ways to implement a parser for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was playing around with your string and based on the comments that your string is incorrectly formed so I have devised a method using `Regular Expressions` to parse out the data from the string in question. Please find the code below to my attempt and a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XLSde4

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         string str = "[{name:{buyerfirstname:Randy, buyermiddlename:null, buyerlastname:Johnson}, buyerfullname:Randy Johnson, businessname:null}]";
         showMatch(str, @"(?<=[:,])(.*?)(?=\}[,\]])");
    }

     private static void showMatch(string text, string expr) {
         MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);
         string[] matches=new string[10000];
         foreach (Match m in mc) {
            string tailored=m.Value.Trim().Replace("{","");
            matches = Regex.Split(tailored, ","); 
            for(int i=0;i<matches.Length;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(matches[i].ToString().Trim());
            }   
         }
      }
}
```

Output:

```
buyerfirstname:Randy
buyermiddlename:null
buyerlastname:Johnson
buyerfullname:Randy Johnson
businessname:null
```

I hope this helps you out or atleast give you a direction to start somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Need some tweaking but atleast got some help

Comment: @mohammedzaid Glad to hear that sir.